# Montando banco de dados, como faço essa relação?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-estrangeira, diagrama

Estou montando o diagrama EER de um ERP. Praticamente todas as tabelas possui uma coluna chamada "id_company" que faz relação com a tabela "companies". Isso porque p usuário poderá gerenciar uma ou mais empresa, e quero que cada registro das outras tabelas sejam específicos daquela empresa.

Está certo inserir a coluna "id_company" em praticamente todas as tabelas ou eu deveria fazer isso de alguma outra forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou lhe fazer uma pergunta que vai ajudar:

**Está certo inserir a coluna `id_company` em praticamente todas as tabelas?**

Só você pode dizer isso. Só você sabe os requisitos do seu sistema. Se existe alguma razão para ter essas colunas em quase todas as tabelas, está certo.

Provavelmente o que você está fazendo chama-se [*multitenancy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). O oposto disto é ter uma banco de dados para cada empresa e não misturar os dados. Cada uma dessas abordagens tem vantagens e desvantagens.

Não é muito comum fazer desta forma, eu evitaria mas não conheço seu caso. Sem entrar muito nos detalhes que não é o foco da pergunta, entre as principais vantagens estão:

- é ser mais fácil fazer consolidação de dados de todas as empresas (se precisa);
- e facilidades para dar manutenção já que feito para uma está feito para todas.

As principais desvantagens são:

- a inflexibilidade para adaptar o esquema para as diferentes empresas;
- dificuldade de filtrar dados que realmente interessam.

Mas para tudo existe solução, é só uma questão do que é mais fácil para sua situação.

O usuário pode gerenciar mais de uma empresa ao mesmo tempo? Como isso é tratado na aplicação? Isto ajuda decidir.

Com os comentários adicionais eu diria que está certo. Ainda digo que não posso falar sem conhecer toda a situação real. Mas se `Company` significa filial então faz mais sentido manter tudo no mesmo banco de dados e obviamente cada linha entrada precisará ter uma identificação de qual filial ela pertence. Tem que saber como filtrar os dados sempre que for trabalhar com apenas uma filial - isto costuma ser mais comum - mas parece ser um trabalho pequeno perto das vantagens de ter tudo junto para a manipulação pela mesma pessoa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Este ERP não chega a dar a possibilidade de controlar mais de uma empresa matriz. Neste caso, o usuário principal (administrador) tem controle sobre os outros usuários + o cadastramento das filiais. Só que quanto a lançar produtos, cadastrar funcionários etc. Só é possível para aquela sessão, ou seja, cada usuário está ligado a somente uma empresa. Neste caso, o administrador sempre estará ligado somente a empresa matriz. Será que ficou confuso?

Comment: Empresa e filial são conceitos completamente distintos. Foi você que fez esta modelagem? Você escolheu usar nomes em inglês? Você domina inglês? Talvez a confusão começou aí. Se "company" é filial, aí eu **provavelmente** colocaria no mesmo banco de dados.

Comment: Sim, eu tenho o inglês fluente, inclusive fiz esta mesma pergunta no stackoverflow inglês, mas não obtive respostas. Preferi usar company "empresa" para retratar tanto a matriz quanto as filiais (pois uma filial não deixa de ser uma empresa).

Answer (score 6):

Se você precisar emitir relatórios comparativos entre as empresas ou relatórios unificados (Ex: somatória do Lucro bruto) vai precisar por no mínimo nas tabelas relacionadas a movimentação de produtos, serviços e financeiro. Os cadastros ficam a critério dos requisitos (se todas as empresas terão os mesmos produtos, por exemplo).

A outra possibilidade que posso imaginar para um operador ter acesso a várias empresas seria criar de forma dinâmica um banco para cada empresa e outro só para registrar os operadores e suas permissões para cada área de cada empresa.

O que vai determinar qual método usar é a integração entre as empresas.

Eu possuo um cliente em que cada banco de cada filial fica em uma cidade diferente, eu apresentei as possibilidades e ele optou por uma terceira... O banco de cada filial é totalmente independente da outra ou seja o operador que existe numa não existe na outra.

Pessoalmente eu não gostei, mas ele é quem escolhe o que quer, e se tiver que mudar depois, cobro de novo, hehehe.